# Not understanding why 116+14 = -126 (CS50)

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to figure out the Vigenere problemset of CS50 and I'm not getting what I'm expecting. I wrote out the case I used on paper and did the math by hand and when I run the program I'm getting something entirely different. It's addition and the program is working for values that are not wrapping around the alphabet. I'm using the argument 'bacon' and the string received by the user is going to be 'Meet'. The program is running fine for the first 3 letters 'Mee', but when it reaches 't' it doesn't work too well...

The program runs by finding the ASCII value of the argument which is converted into uppercase, in this case it's 'BACON', and then those values are used to increment the corresponding i'th value in the string 'Meet'. I had my code show how much it was going to increment the i'th value in the string, and the value of the i'th character in the string. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated !

P.S. this problem involves the last 'else if' conditional within the last for loop.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    int main(int argc, string argv[])
    {
        // make sure command-line receives only one argument, excluding file 
           name
        if( argc != 2)
        {
            printf("incorrect # of arguments, terminating program\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // make sure that only aplhabets are entered for argument
        for(int i = 0,n=strlen(argv[1]); i<n; i++)
        {
            if(toupper(argv[1][i]) < 65 || toupper(argv[1][i]) > 90  )
            {
                printf("non-alphabetical character found in argument, terminating program\n");
                return 2;
            }

        // convert argument to all UPPERCASE, to make lower and upper affect plain-text similarily
        }
        for(int i = 0,n=strlen(argv[1]); i<n; i++)
        {
            argv[1][i] = toupper(argv[1][i]);
        }


       printf("plaintext: ");
       string plain = get_string();

       printf("ciphertext: ");

       int m = strlen(argv[1]);
       for(int i = 0,j=0,n=strlen(plain); i < n; i++,j++)
       {
           if(j == m)
           {
               j = 0;
           }

           int increment = argv[1][i] - 65;     // key: A = 0, B = 1 
           printf("value of increment: %i\n",increment);

           if(plain[i] >= 65 && plain[i] <= 90)     // check for case of plain-text
           {
               plain[i] = (int) plain[i] + increment;
               if((int) plain[i] > 90)              // see if wrapping occurs
               {
                   increment = (int) plain[i]%90;
                   plain[i] = 65 + increment;
               }

           }
           else if(plain[i] >= 97 && plain[i] <= 122)
           {
               printf("letter %c, value %i\n",plain[i],(int)plain[i]);
               plain[i] = (int)plain[i] + increment;
               printf("position %i, value %i\n",i,(int)plain[i]);
               if((int) plain[i] > 122)
               {
                   increment = (int) plain[i]%122;
                   plain[i] = 97 + increment;
               }
           }
           else{
               j--;
           }
       }
       printf("%s\n",plain);

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your program is using signed char variables, which have a range that goes from -128 to 127, and you are experiencing an integer overflow.

Comment: check `CHAR_MAX`

Comment: signed char: 130 becomes -126.

Comment: Glad we could help you. I've posted my comment as an answer.

Comment: `if(toupper(argv[1][i]) < 65 || toupper(argv[1][i]) > 90  )`?  No, just no.  There are reasons functions such as `isupper()`, `islower()`, etc are a part of *standard* C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is using signed char variables, which have a range that goes from -128 to +127, and you are experiencing an integer overflow.